# Dynamic number of buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

In the `onCreate` method of my `Activity` I know the number of `Buttons` which I want in `col0`. In the following example it are four `Buttons`. Then my `TextView` `v0` gets the `android:layout_weight` set to `number of buttons minus one` (this is because `v1` should be of the same height as all the `Buttons`). Instead of providing for each possible number of buttons an own xml file it would be much nicer, if one could generalize such that dynamic java codes somehow produces the appropriate layout. How is that possible?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col0"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            style="@style/MyButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            style="@style/MyButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            style="@style/MyButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            style="@style/MyButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you not edit the weight programatically?

Comment: I think the problem is the part of the generation of the `Buttons`.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? Seems like nobody has a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prepare all the possible ids, here 10 buttons max (put it in `res/values`) :

<kbd>ids.xml</kbd>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="b0" />
    <item type="id" name="b1" />
    <item type="id" name="b2" />
    <item type="id" name="b3" />
    <item type="id" name="b4" />
    <item type="id" name="b5" />
    <item type="id" name="b6" />
    <item type="id" name="b7" />
    <item type="id" name="b8" />
    <item type="id" name="b9" />
</resources>
```

If you are using API >= 17, you can avoid this file and use [View.generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

**If you don't need ids, skip the above part**

Then, here is your main layout :

<kbd>main.xml</kbd>

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col0"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">    
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, use the code to generate your layout :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
int buttonsNumber = 5; // Put here your number of buttons
LinearLayout col0 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.col0);

for(int i = 0; i < buttonsNumber; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setId(R.id.class.getField("b"+i).getInt(null));
        // Since API Level 17, you can also use View.generateViewId()
        newButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));
        col0.addView(newButton);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Unknown button id !
        // We skip it
    }
}

TextView v0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.v0);
v0.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.match_parent, 0, buttonsNumber - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In `@style/MyButton` it says `<item name="android:layout_height">0dip</item><item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>`. This should make all buttons of same height such that the total height of `col0` is used. Unfortunately, using your code all buttons get smaller height such that a big part of `col0` remains black. How do I fix that? And is it important that each button has an ID? I extended your for-loop and save references of the buttons in an array. So I still can access them without an ID.

Comment: The id is not mandatory. I had it accordingly to your specifications. About the Button size issue I don't know. I guessed you had already tested the layout, and only the generation part was the issue

Comment: Yeah, I did test it. It works fine if I use my XML file. But with your approach everything seems to be correct but the height. Maybe we have to tell col0 somehow, that it should recalculate the heights after adding the buttons.

Comment: I will push my investigation asap.

Comment: Indeed it was not working. I did not found a solution based on `styles` so I put the style part in the code `newButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));` and removed the `custombutton` template. It should work now. Solution has been edited.

Comment: Thanks. My style has still some more properties. So I decided to generate the Button like you did in your first post `(Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_button, null);` and then additionally call `setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));`. This is the best approach for my purpose I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
int buttonsNumber = YOUR_BUTTONS_NUMBER;
LinearLayout col0 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.col0);
Button button = new Button(getContext()); // or create xml view for button and get it with findViewById

// adding buttons
for(int i = 0; i < buttonsNumber; i++)
    col0.addView(button);

// setting weight
TextView v0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.v0);
v0.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.match_parent, 0, buttonsNumber - 1));
```

Comment: First of all we shouldn't add all the time the same `Button`, but that's no problem to fix. The problem in your solution is that the new `Buttons` look totally different from those generated by the xml layout.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain thats because the style hasnt been set. Try findviewbyid to get your existing xml buttons

Comment: How can you set the style? Can you post some code? I don't understand what you mean by "Try findviewbyid to get your existing xml buttons". I thought we are trying to solve the problem without use of xml to make the number of buttons dynamic.

Comment: You cannot set a view's style programmatically. I don't know what is your "MyButton" style. Try set parameters individually or create my_button.xml for your button and use it Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.layout.button);

Comment: I tried your `findViewById` approach. But this method with the id of the Button in an external layout file supplied always returns `null`.